# How to add video to the asp.net websites

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have read a lot of articals to add video in to the asp.net web page. So, its time to ask the question.
I don't have any idea that how to add video into my webpage.
Can anyone help me for this???

Comment: You have read a lot of articles about adding video to asp.net page and still you have no idea how to do it? Then what is the point of reading these articles? Did you try _anything_ as code? Read [FAQ], [ask] and [help]

Comment: I am not able to implement that on to my webpage. I didnt found any code that will work for me. If you have any idea so please share.

Comment: Why not? I mean, what is so hard to put in a video control in a browser? What did you try? BLindly copy pasting never works, outside of the phantasies of those that hope to avoid learning by copy/pasting. So, what did you try? Video playback is standard HTML and well documented by now. Heck, youtube embedding is extremely well documented and it answers the question as you ask it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me just ask snippily: What exactly did you read?

Playing back a video in an asp.net site is as easy as embedding youtube, and this is extremely well documented "Embedd youtube" in google helps a lot.

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/web_graphics/article.php/3480061

has in depth tutorials for example.

You say nothing else about self hosting the video etc. , so - embedding a youtube video fullfills the requirements of the question.

Took me 10 seconds to find that tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

assume you have an mp4 video

```
<video controls>

   <source src="video example.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   your browser doesn't support this video type

</video>
```

not every browser will be able to play .mp4 video's
you can add multiple video's with different file extensions like this

```
<video controls>

    <source src="video example.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="video examle.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video example.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    your browser doesn't support this video type

</video>
```